# Sizing image but need math equation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Here's my issue.

I have a website mainly of images, but the image producer creates them to be too big for an average screen size so I'm looking for math equations to use to automatically size them to my screen.

In the image you see, the big image box has dimensions IX,IY. and the formatted image box has dimensions X,Y and the screen space has dimensions SX,SY.

X and Y need to be less than SX and SY respectively. IX or IY need to be bigger than SX or SY.

When the image is downsized, the scaling needs to be intact regardless of the orientation of the image and there always needs to be a fixed available width in the screen area for text.

This is a PHP equivalent code I used to try to produce the results:

```
    $pc=($xsw/$xsh);
    if ($xsw > $xsh){
            $xsh=intval($xsh/$pc);if ($xsh > $ch){$xsh=$ch;}
            $xsw=($xsh*$pc);
    }else{
            $xsw=intval($xsw*$pc);if ($xsw > $cw){$xsw=$cw;}
            $xsh=($xsw/$pc);
    }
```

But I feel my math is way off.

Here's examples of what I'm trying to achieve:

If the screen size is 800x600 and I want 200px room for text on the side and the image is 1000x500 in size, then I want the image to be 600x300.

If the screen size is 1024x768 and I want 124px room for text on the side and the image is 2000x2000 in size, then I want the image to be 768x768 in size.

The reason why I ask this is because I want to make the website not require side-scrolling from the use of oversized images.

Does anyone have a good equation or set of equations I can try?

Answer (score 1):

First, find the maximum $X$ and $Y$ you will accept, which are $SX, SY$ minus the room you want for text.  Then find the reduction factor, which is $\min(\frac X{IX},\frac Y{IY})$  Scale by the reduction factor (which, if the original is small may be greater than $1$ and you are expanding, that is OK).  One dimension will give you extra room for text:  fill it up.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-code:

```
RawImageRatio = IY/IX;
X = SX - TextSpace;
Y = X * RawImageRatio;
If IY/Y>IX/X then
    Scale = Y/IY;
else
    Scale = X/IX;
```

Comment: I'm trying to apply that equation but it doesn't quite work in a portrait situation. Is there an equation I can use to see portrait orientation without scrolling? Your equation works for me if I did landscape pictures. The picture sizes I'm actually working with are 800x532 and 532x800 respectively and my screen resolution is 800x600 and I have about a 600x750 usable space for the image (after textspace deduction)

Comment: You just need to set a maximum Y value in that case - and if X*RawImageValue is greater than this, then set Y=MaxY and X=Y/RawImageValue